# String concat in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php script that returns a resultset from mysql database like that:

## nombre_musico          apellidos_musico

- Rafael                 Ruda
- Antonio Manuel         Rios
- Alejandro              Astola

The source code to concat string of musicians:

```
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
            $apellido = str_replace("\r","",$fila->apellidos_musico);;
            $nombre = str_replace("\r","",$fila->nombre_musico);
            $musicos .= $nombre . " " . $apellido .",";
        }
```

the sql query is:

```
    $sql = "select gr.nombre_grupo, gr.anyo_creacion, gr.descripcion, ms.nombre_musico, ms.apellidos_musico\n"
    . "from musico ms, canta_para cp, grupo gr\n"
    . "where ms.id_musico = cp.musico_id and gr.id_grupo = cp.grupo_id and gr.nombre_grupo = '".$name_group."'";
```

and the code to execute the query is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
```

I want to obtain result like this:

```
"musicos":"Rafael Ruda,Antonio Manuel Rios,Alejandro Astola"
```

but the result I obtain is:

```
"Rafael Ruda,Antonio Manuel Rios,"
```

What I must do to obtain te correct concatenated string. I wonder for a little help as soon as possible.

Comment: what field are those names contained in?

Comment: ms.nombre_musico, ms.apellidos_musico in the select

Comment: Is the problem that you only get two names? Or is the problem that you want to see "musicos" : "..."

Comment: the problem is that i got two names instead of three the "musicos":"..." is a json property that returns the php script

Answer (score 1):

this will return exactly the format you entered:

```
SELECT CONCAT('\"musicos\":',gr.nombre_grupo,', ',gr.anyo_creacion,', ',gr.descripcion,', ',ms.nombre_musico,', ',ms.apellidos_musico)
```

Comment: That is not what i want. I want to concat the three names and assign it to an json object property which name is "musicos"